# MVC4 model binding to a dictionary (breaking change?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have the following inputs on a page:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.TextBox(String.Format("someData[{0}].Key", 0))
    @Html.TextBox(String.Format("someData[{0}].Key", 1))

    @Html.TextBox(String.Format("someData[{0}].Value", 0))
    @Html.TextBox(String.Format("someData[{0}].Value", 1))

    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
}
```

I was under the impression that posting this data should bind to an IDictionary via the default model binder in MVC. However, I want the key of the dictionary to be numeric:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(IDictionary<long?, string> someData)
{
    //...
}
```

I use Javascript to validate these fields on the client side, however if I turn JS off, and submit the form without entering anything in the boxes, I get an `InvalidCastException` saying that the model binder cannot bind to the someData collection.

I'm sure that in previous versions of MVC (we've upgraded recently) and because the Dictionary key is nullable `(long?)` that if invalid data was entered for the '.Key' inputs (i.e. non numeric), the dictionary just omitted the entry in the collection.

Surely you can submit an empty form without JS enabled in this case? My Action is not even hit (breakpoint) when I submit the form so I can't catch the error myself and add to the ModelState...

Comment: Why are you not using a strongly typed model binding approach ?

Comment: It's complicated! The page does have a ViewModel, however this is very bespoke functionality added into an existing view (which is shared) and only in use under very specific circumstances. The joys of trying to add to some not-so-nice legacy code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me with:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IDictionary<long?, string> someData)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do some stuff here...
    }
    return View();
}
```

However, posting with null values, will yield an invalid cast and is a known issue that has been identified here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/373

Comment: Looks like this is an actual breaking change then. Wow :|